# Trying to show and convert a 2 byte unicode string

Tags: c#, wpf, unicode, utf-16

I have a C interface method I'm calling in a c# WPF project. The method returns a 2 byte Unicode (UTF-16, if I'm not mistaken) string via a `StringBuilder`. I am trying to show this 2 byte Unicode string in a WPF `TextBox` control, and writing this to a `.txt` file.

The result in both the `TextBox` and `.txt` file seems to be unreadable.

I have tried converting the Unicode (UTF-16) string to ANSI, but this doesn't do the trick either.

Following is both the `DllImport` and the code sample where I try to convert the string into something readable.

```
[DllImport("cdll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern static int ChannelID(int uHandle, uint uChannel, StringBuilder szID);

for (uint i = 0; i <= numChannels - 1; i++)
{
     StringBuilder sbId = new StringBuilder(32);
     ChannelID(_handle, i, sbId);
     string val = "";
     UnicodeEncoding unicode = new UnicodeEncoding();
     val = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Default, unicode.GetBytes(sbId.ToString())));
     File.AppendAllText(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "dump.txt", sbId.ToString() + " - ", Encoding.Unicode);                
     textBox1.AppendText(val + " - ");
     textBox1.AppendText(sbId.ToString() + " - ");
}
```

The string is being read from a device connected with Bluetooth. The device is used for measuring things like temperature, air moisture, air pressure, ...

So the input is a Unicode string with for example °c, and the output on screen and in the txt file should be a readable version of this (eg. ansi).

Another bit of information that might be important, the C method was originally used in an excel Macro VBA project, for this reason this 2 byte Unicode encoding is used.

**Solution**

The problem had nothing to do with the CharSet in the `DllImport`, but rather with the CallingConvention. After contacting the people who made the C library they told me they passed us a wrong example code. The correct `DllImport` is this one:

```
[DllImport("cdll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
```

After adding this the data came through correctly, without having to do any conversions.

Comment: what's the input and expected output?

Comment: I've added the input (result from the c method) and the output I expect in the file in my question.

Comment: If the method manages to put the string correctly in the `StringBuilder`, then there is no conversion needed at all. Just use `szID.ToString()` to get the string, and you can use that directly when you write to the file and put it in the text box. If not, then you have something that is not an UFT-16 string but something else, so to convert that you need to know what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're "destroying" your string in this line:

```
val = Encoding.Default.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Default, unicode.GetBytes(sbId.ToString())));
```

As .NET is fully capable of working with double-byte unicode characters, the string you want should already be in `sbId`, so ideally, the following should work:

```
val = sbId.ToString();
```

What does the debugger show when you stop at the above line and inspect the value of `sbId`?

Comment: When trying to show the ToString() method of my stringbuilder I still get an unreadable sting, that's why I started tinkering with Encoding conversions.

Some characters are readable however, for example, one line returns ppm CO, in which case CO is readable. The ppm is probably the unicode character.

Comment: I've +1'ed your answer, once I get some feedback from the people who wrote the C lib I'm using, I'll mark this as answer since it validated my suspicions that something might be going wrong in the C code.

Comment: As I said I'm marking this as answer, the actual cause of the problem is added in my question, with the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
 CharSet = CharSet.Unicode
```

This is where you went wrong, it isn't Unicode.  You **must** use CharSet.Ansi instead.

A unicode string requires two 0 bytes to terminate the string.  The native code only generates one.  The normal fate is an AccessViolationException but you are not often lucky enough to get one.  Finding two adjacent binary zeros in memory is a bit too likely.  So you'll end up with a very long string, just random garbage.

Just declare it what it really is, `CharSet.Ansi`.  And you don't need that Encoding.Convert() code anymore either.

Comment: This doesn't work either, the result is similar to using CharSet.Unicode. Currently the people who wrote the C dll I'm using are looking into it, it's possible the C code is passing the strings wrong. The comments here kind of validated that idea :)

Answer (score 0):

As it's not clear what's the expected output, still you may try:

```
 byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("°c");
 Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
```

this gives output as ??c